# Adding specific every N rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, rank, ceil

I'm trying to figure out how to select from this sample table and sum first 2 records, next two records, etc…. I have been trying to use rank and ceil but i'm clearly not managing to achieve success so thanks in advance to the human out there that can help.

```
recid  text1  int_value

1      Blue   3

2      Green  4

3      Yellow 6

4      Red    9

5      Purple 34

6      Black  3
```

to achieve desired result of summing 1st/2nd row, then 3rd/4th row, then 5th/6th row something like:

```
sumvalueis

7

15

37
```

In reality the table might have more rows but this is a sample with only 6 rows and adding int_value for 1st/2nd, 3rd/4th, 5th/6th, etc..

Comment: Firstly, there is not such a thing as `first 2 records`, nor `next` if you don't specify an order. What is that order? `recid` maybe? Secondly, there is no such a thing as `rank` in MySQL... so that's why you failed at it :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query:

```
SELECT sum(int_value) SumValueIs FROM (
  SELECT int_value, ceil((@rank := @rank + 1) / 2) aGroup
  FROM t, (SELECT @rank := 0) init
  ORDER BY recid
) s
GROUP BY aGroup
```

Here is the output:

```
| SUMVALUEIS |
|------------|
|          7 |
|         15 |
|         37 |
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3afd5/1).

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.  It won't be fast but looking at your example data it should suit the purpose.

```
SELECT @rownum := 1,  SUM(int_value) AS sumvalueis FROM (
    SELECT t.*, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
    FROM your_table t
) AS ranked
GROUP BY FLOOR(rank/2)
```

Where the `rank/2` is the number of rows to group.